# ListPlot in a Loop

Tags: plotting

I have the following program which generates the plot from a data list(i.e. Data1). However I want to print some plots for some values of the parameter "**a**". How would I proceed to print the scatter plots in the For loop (side by side as a table preferrably). The Code is as follows.

```
Data1 = {};
del = 0.1;
delx = 1/del;
n = 10;
a = 2;(* I would like to use various values of this variable in a loop throughout the code*)
(*************From Here************)
Vx = SparseArray[{}, {n, n}];

For[k = -2*Pi/a, k <= 2*Pi/a, k = k + 0.01,
ConsMat = ((k^2)/2)*IdentityMatrix[n];
dfdx = (SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> -I*k*delx, 
Band[{2, 1}] -> I*k*delx, {1, n} -> 
I*k*delx, {n, 1} -> -I*k*delx}, {n, n}]);
d2fdx2 = -1*
SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> -(delx^2), Band[{1, 2}] -> delx^2, 
Band[{2, 1}] -> delx^2, {1, n} -> delx^2, {n, 1} -> delx^2}, {n,
n}];

p = 1;
For[x = 1, x <= 5, x = x + 5/n,
Vx[[p, p]] = (Cos[2 Pi*x/a] - 1);
p++;
];
p = 1;


Hamil = (dfdx + d2fdx2 + ConsMat) + Vx;
EigenVal = Eigenvalues[Hamil];

For[j = 1, j <= Length[EigenVal], j++,
Coord = {k, EigenVal[[j]]};
AppendTo[Data1, Coord];
];

];
ListPlot[Data1]
(**************To Here********************)
```

Comment: [It will help you if you don't use `For` loops in Mathematica.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica)  You can use `Print` to display multiple plots in a loop, e.g. `Do[Print@Plot[Sin[k x], {x, 0, 10}], {k, 1, 5}]`.  Or you can use `Table` to collect them into a list.  `Table[Plot[Sin[k x], {x, 0, 10}], {k, 1, 5}]`. Use `Column` or `Row` to format the list.

Comment: Next time please try to show a *minimal* example. Could you not have illustrated the same problem with much less code?  See http://sscce.org/ for guidance.

Comment: Thank you for your information.I would definitely keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function using Module which returns the plot.

```
listP[a_] :=
  Module[{Data1, del, delx, n, k, Vx, dfdx, d2fdx2, ConsMat, p, x, 
    Hamil, EigenVal, j, Coord},
   Data1 = {}; del = 0.1; delx = 1/del; n = 10;
   Vx = SparseArray[{}, {n, n}];
   For[k = -2*Pi/a, k <= 2*Pi/a, k = k + 0.01, 
    ConsMat = ((k^2)/2)*IdentityMatrix[n];
    dfdx = (SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> -I*k*delx, 
        Band[{2, 1}] -> I*k*delx, {1, n} -> 
         I*k*delx, {n, 1} -> -I*k*delx}, {n, n}]);
    d2fdx2 = -1*
      SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> -(delx^2), Band[{1, 2}] -> delx^2, 
        Band[{2, 1}] -> delx^2, {1, n} -> delx^2, {n, 1} -> 
         delx^2}, {n, n}];
    p = 1;
    For[x = 1, x <= 5, x = x + 5/n, Vx[[p, p]] = (Cos[2 Pi*x/a] - 1);
     p++;];
    p = 1;
    Hamil = (dfdx + d2fdx2 + ConsMat) + Vx;
    EigenVal = Eigenvalues[Hamil];
    For[j = 1, j <= Length[EigenVal], j++, Coord = {k, EigenVal[[j]]};
     AppendTo[Data1, Coord];];];
   ListPlot[Data1, Frame -> True]
   ];
```

Then create a table of plots for different values of a

```
Table[listP[a], {a, 1, 3}]
```